# Jupyter after installation "Anaconda"

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to work with Anaconda for sometime, now i am trying to install it and facing some issues with `Jupyter`.eatch time i try to launch `Jupyter` i get

http://localhost:8892/undefined/tree

And is there a way to change the default browser from Internet Explorer to Google Crome ?

[image: A screen shot]

Comment: 1. Navigate to Settings. You can get there from the Start menu. 

2. Select System. 
3. Click Default apps in the left pane.
4. Click Microsoft Edge under the "Web browser" heading. ...
5. Select the new browser (ex: Chrome) in the menu that pops up.

Answer (score 0):

## launching from command line

You can type `jupyter-notebook.exe --help` to get the command line options.  The one you are interested in is shown below:

```
--browser=<Unicode> (NotebookApp.browser)
Default: ''
Specify what command to use to invoke a web browser when opening the
notebook. If not specified, the default browser will be determined by the
`webbrowser` standard library module, which allows setting of the BROWSER
environment variable to override it.
```

So `jupyter-notebook.exe --browser='chrome'` should work.  You could incorporate this command into a Windows shortcut or consider the alternative below.

## changing your config

From the command line type `jupyter-notebook.exe --generate-config` which will create a config file called `jupyter_notebook_config.py` located in your `C:\Users\<user>\.jupyter` directory.  Open this file and uncomment the line containing `c.NotebookApp.browser`.  Then set its value to be `'chrome'`.